# Loop with Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that is working but I am trying to improve it.
The actual code is like this:

```
Sub Main()
    frequencyinterval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime frequencyinterval, "Sheet1.Subordinate"
End Sub

Sub Subordinate
    'Do some things
    Call Sheet1.Main 
End Sub
```

It seems to me that something like this would be better than calling Main from the sub. Problem is that it shuts down Excel.

```
Do While Cells(10, 1).Value = "Running"
    Frequencyinterval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime frequencyinterval, "Sheet.Main"
Loop
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

I thought that recursive calls were bad. However, nothing else works. A wait within the do while stops the data feed of incomong stock prices.

After the program has run for a few hours my computer goes into slow motion and later just locks up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your second example will set a huge number of `OnTime`'s, since the loop will execute numerous times per second, for as long as the value in A10 is "Running"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Main once to start the loop

```
Sub Main()

    If Cells(10, 1).Value = "Running" Then

        'do some things
        Call CheckTheThing()

        'Schedule the next run
        frequencyinterval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
        Application.OnTime frequencyinterval, "Sheet1.Main"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, With this suggestion I believe I wlii still need to call Main from the Sub. Is it ok to repeatedly call a procedure from a sub? The purpose of the program is to monitor an external variable each 10 seconds over a period of 7 hours.@TimWilliams

Comment: You just call Main once to start the loop.  Once it has run CheckTheThing it will schedule the next run.

Comment: OK Tim, I finally got it. The program is working correctly now. Thank you very much.